# NLP task of arranging words in the correct order?

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, huggingface-transformers

Is there any state-of-the-art deep learning model that can acomplish the task of arranging a bunch of words in the correct order?

For example,

- **Input**: boy that killed have must they
- **Expected output**: They must have killed that boy

I would appreciate some insights,

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/allenschmaltz/word_ordering

https://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/slides/emnlp16_order.pdf

Following the above work, you can replace the LSTM encoder with pretrained language models such as BERT.